# Do these sentence make sense?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrases, sentence

Currently writing a essay about the significance of food. Does this sentence make sense?

"Food in many ways is more important to us than we take it granted for. It can represent a variety of ideas and act as a catalyst for fostering relationships and memories."

Comment: Your first sentence does not make sense. The expression is **take it for granted**, meaning  'accept it as normal without thinking'. and it doesn't follow logically from 'more important than'.

Comment: @KateBunting any suggestions on how to make it make sense?

Comment: This forum is not supposed to provide a proofreading service; however. I see someone else has done it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well! Honestly, the structure of all these sentences has less or negligible aesthetic value. Do these sentences make any sense? The straight answer from my side would be a big 'no' because these truly are not making any sense.

Food is an immensely interesting subject-line and I don't want to make it monotonous by adding a few more paragraphs preaching the grammar. Instead, I would try to re-write these while keeping the aesthetic value alive so that these sound more interesting.

> Line 1: Often we take food for granted but in many ways, the
>   importance of food is beyond our imagination.
>
> Line 2: It can be the source of a variety of ideas. In fact, foods can
>   act as a catalyst to boost relationships and help to cherish memories.

***In line 2, I felt the last part was pretty meaningful, so I have not modified it much.***

I hope my answer helps you with your project.

Comment: It does! Thank you very much. English isn't my first language so I make mistakes often. I think what you've suggested is exactly what I was trying to say!

Comment: Don't worry! One day, you would rise like a phoenix by taking lessons from all those minor mistakes.  I am glad that you found this answer helpful. Wish you all the best for your project.